# Find best intersect (most elements) between Order (haystack) and Pricerules (needle)

Tags: sqlite, cte, recursive, set-returning-functions

**Full disclosure**
I have posted [a greater scoped question at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77247767/) a couple of days ago with a bounty (no answers yet).

#### Scope here

How can a CTE be used to find a match with the most elements?
For the order `403` i want to find out

- which pricerule is an `INTERSECT` for all features ordered (`FeatureId in (1,2,3)`)
- for a given featureId (1).

For `FeatureId = 1` and `OrderId=403` the best matching pricerule is `PriceRuleId = 103`.

From table `OrderPositions`
[image: OrderPositions]

And table `FeatureCombinations`

[image: FeatureCombinations]

I want to find each set (pair) with the most elements in both tables.

#### SQL Statemens to create the tables with records

Create tables

```
CREATE TABLE FeatureCombinations(
  PriceRuleId INTEGER,
  FeatureId   INTEGER   
);

CREATE TABLE OrderPositions(
  Id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY, 
  OrderId   INTEGER,   
  FeatureId   INTEGER
);
```

Create records

```
INSERT INTO FeatureCombinations (PriceRuleId, FeatureId)
VALUES (101, 1), (102, 1), (102, 2),
       (103, 1), (103, 2),(103, 3), 
       (105, 7), (106, 7), (106, 8); 
       
INSERT INTO OrderPositions(Id, OrderId, FeatureId)
VALUES (211, 401, 1), (221, 402, 1),(222, 402, 2),
(231, 403, 1),(232, 403, 2),(233, 403, 3);
```

This is my query attempt but it runs forever so it must be wrong

```
-- DANGER  runs forever
WITH RECURSIVE cte_OrderPositions (PriceRuleId, FeatureId) AS (
    SELECT fc.PriceRuleId, op.FeatureId
    FROM OrderPositions op LEFT JOIN FeatureCombinations fc
    ON op.FeatureId = fc.FeatureId
    WHERE op.OrderId = 403 
  
    UNION ALL
  
    SELECT c.PriceRuleId, op.FeatureId
    FROM OrderPositions op
    JOIN cte_OrderPositions c ON c.FeatureId = op.FeatureId 
    -- DANGER  runs forever
)

SELECT * FROM cte_OrderPositions;
-- DANGER  runs forever
```